# Where can close a Lettuce Redis connection in my Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I have initialized the Spring Boot app with Lettuce(io.lettuce.core.api) configuration like this

```
@Configuration
class RedisConfiguration  {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHostname;
    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    private StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> redisConnection;
    private static RedisClient redisClient;

    @Bean
    public RedisCommands connectionFactory() {
        RedisURI redisURI = RedisURI.create(redisHostname,redisPort);
        redisClient = RedisClient.create(redisURI);
        redisConnection = redisClient.connect();
        RedisCommands<String, String> syncCommands = 
        redisConnection.sync();
        return syncCommands;
    }
}
```

I want to call `redisClient.shutdown();` when application shuts down or exits. What is the right place to terminate the redis connection ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Using `@PreDestroy`:

```
    @PreDestroy
    public StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> redisConnection() {
        redisConnection.close();
        redisClient.close();
    }
```

2. Via `@Bean` methods

Make sure to expose `RedisClient` and `StatefulRedisConnection` as beans. Command interfaces (`RedisCommands`) do not expose a `close()` method.

```
@Configuration
class RedisConfiguration  {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHostname;
    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> redisClient() {
        RedisURI redisURI = RedisURI.create(redisHostname,redisPort);
        return RedisClient.create(redisURI);
        redisConnection = redisClient.connect();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> redisConnection(RedisClient client) {
        return client.connect();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCommands redisCommands(StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection) {
        return connection.sync();
    }
}
```

The first method is shorter while the `@Bean` approach lets you interact with intermediate objects in your application.

Comment: Is it safe to create a `RedisAdvancedClusterCommands` as a singleton spring bean and share it across multiple service threads?
In most examples online, I see `StatefulRedisClusterConnection` being declared as a bean and `RedisAdvancedClusterCommands` being instantiated per service call?
However, the fact that the interface is marked as `thread-safe` in the docs and the absence of `RedisTransactionalCommands` or a similar interface from it makes me think it is safe to use across service threads.